# Small moments when I can't seem to do anything

Tags: actions

I am using Blender version 2.79. There are moments when I can't move or do anything. Just small moments when I can't do anything.
-The best way I can describe it, is no matter where I click or what button I press I can't move or do anything. It's like everything stays still because it want's me to do or not do something.

What would be the correct button to push? Where do I click?
What am I supposed to do?

Comment: It seems to me that you are creating a scene that exceeds the capacity of your machine. But we know nothing about your project, your computer or any other useful information to help you. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings

Comment: if it happens while you're in Rendered viewport shading, you should decrease the preview sampling ratio, in my case I use a ratio of 3 and it's enough

Comment: I'll try just simple geometry, still had that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a right click. For example, using circle select needs a right click to accept the selection and escape back to normal.

Comment: That solved the problem. Right clicking. Thanks.